using date metadata from docx, pdf files for Azure cognitive search
I'm uploading a lot of DocX and PDF files into blob storage to be used in Azure cognitive search. I'm using it to experiment with some AI capabilities I already, and it works well but I would like to try the filterable freshness. I'm not sure how the metadata for these PDF files (e.g., 'author', 'date', 'title') can be added through a skill. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks
{
  "@odata.context": ... ,
  "@odata.etag": ... ,
  "name": "freshness",
  "description": "Skillset to chunk documents and generate embeddings",
  "skills": [
    {
      ...
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Util.ShaperSkill",
      "name": "#3",
      "description": "Extracts metadata from the document",
      "context": "/document",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name": "metadata_creation_date",
          "source": "/document/metadata_creation_date"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "output",
          "targetName": "creationDate"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "cognitiveServices": null,
  "knowledgeStore": null,
  "indexProjections": {
    "selectors": [
      {
        "targetIndexName": "freshness",
        "parentKeyFieldName": "parent_id",
        "sourceContext": "/document/pages/*",
        "mappings": [
          {
            "name": "creationDate",
            "source": "/document/creationDate",
            "sourceContext": null,
            "inputs": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "parameters": {
      "projectionMode": "skipIndexingParentDocuments"
    }
  },
  "encryptionKey": null
}```


why would like it to be added as a skill? By default, the indexer already extract that information, all you have to do is mark those fields as filterable / sortable / facetable during the index creation process

@ThiagoCustodio , maybe I'm too noob in this, where can I get the created date of each file in the indexer ? ... I have been trying to get the date of the file because I want to add scoring profiles based on freshness...

the default indexer will extract metadata_storage_last_modified. There's no metadata about when the file got created. I am afraid you will need to populate it manually

@ThiagoCustodio, maybe last modified could do, I'm currently able to extract the lastmodified date by using #Microsoft.Skills.Util.ShaperSkill, and it gives me this answer as a string ""date": "{"metadata_creation_date":"2024-06-07T14:51:00"}"" but I don't want a string, I want it to be Edm.DateTimeOffset type.

there's no ready to use way. You will need to interact with the index API in order to create another field, then browse through your documents and set the value for the new field.

If you already having the index then you can create new field of type Edm.DateTimeOffset

After creating, map the fields indexer in fieldMappings
"fieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",
      "targetFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",
      "mappingFunction": {
        "name": "base64Encode",
        "parameters": null
      }
    },
        {
            "sourceFieldName":"metadata_storage_last_modified",
            "targetFieldName":"last_modified"
        }
  ]

or
while importing data in the Customize target index
you can make it filterable.

Check the Filterable as shown in the image.

Output:

